# javascript returns NaN in every browser but Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, nan

I build a calculator for my office. It's build in with html, javascript and css. 
It can be found here: http://sebastiaanbeen.nl/calculator-Delcourt/index2.html
I found out that the javascript only works in chrome browser. Tested on Firefox, Safari and IE9
In every browser other than Chrome every output gets a NaN (not a number). While the Chrome version works fine.
This is the first part of my javascript.

```
"use strict";
var kostenleer=0;
var foot=0;
function prijs(form)
{
  foot = parseFloat(form.footinput.value);
  var oppervlakte = parseFloat(form.oppervlakteinput.value);
  var leerprijs = parseFloat(form.leerprijsinput.value) / oppervlakte;
  var extraleer = parseFloat(form.extraleerinput.value);

      kostenleer = (foot * ((extraleer / 100) + 1)) * leerprijs;
      form.leerkosteninput.value = kostenleer;

  }
```

This the first part of my html.

```
<FORM ID="BEREKENING" class="register">

    <h1 class="register-title">Delcourt prijs calculaties</h1>
        <!-- Eerste deel leerkosten berekening-->
        <div class="">
        <hr>
        <h2>Berekening leerkosten</h2>
        <label FOR="footinpunt" TITLE="Aantal ft2 leer">Aantal ft2 leer:</label> 
        <INPUT class="register-input" NAME="footinput" VALUE="0" MAXLENGTH="15" SIZE=15>
<p>
        <label for="leerprijsinput" title="vul leerprijs in">Prijs van het leer per M&sup2 of Sqft</label>
        <INPUT NAME="leerprijsinput" class="register-input" VALUE="0" MAXLENGTH="15" SIZE=15>

        <div class="register-switch">       
        <input type="radio" id="sqft" name="oppervlakteinput" class="register-switch-input"  value="1" checked="">
        <label for="sqft" class="register-switch-label">Sqft</label>
        <input type="radio" id="meter" class="register-switch-input" name="oppervlakteinput" value="10.764">
        <label for="meter" class="register-switch-label">M&sup2</label>

        </div>
<p>
        <label for="extraleerinput">Extra verbruik david in %:</label>
        <INPUT name="extraleerinput" class="register-input" value="0" maxlength="15" size=15>
<p>         
        <label for="calc" title="kosten berekenen"></label>
        <INPUT NAME="calc" class="register-button" VALUE="Bereken" TYPE=BUTTON 
            onClick=prijs(this.form)>
<p>
        <label for="leerkosteninput" title="kosten leer"><b></b></label>
        <INPUT NAME="leerkosteninput" placeholder="Kosten leer" class="register-output" READONLY SIZE=15>

</div>
```

This is my first coding project so it might be a bit messy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could remove "use strict" and check whether it still contains error. Also the `onClick` attribute should be `onclick` no capital **C**.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: Thanks for the input Frank, but unfortunately is still get the same NaN error in my output.